# Percorrer pagina HTML e procurar por links

Tags: javascript, html

Não sei se o titulo ficou esclarecido mas gostaria de saber como percorrer o corpo de uma pagina html e identificar links por exceções...Digamos que quero apenas links que tenham https://site.com/imagens/ em sua url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja se este exemplo utilizando jQuery lhe atende.
Obtém todos os links que tenham no endereço (href) a string "https://site.com/imagens/".
Com o objeto dos links você pode fazer o que você precisar. No exemplo abaixo, coloquei para exibir em uma div.

```js
function ObterLinks()
{
  var links = $('a[href*="https://site.com/imagens/"]'); //obtém todos os links que contenham o endereço.
  var divResultado = $('#divResultado');
  for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
  {
    divResultado.append('<p>' + links[i].href + '</p>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
  <a href="https://site.com/imagens/1.jpg"> Link 1 </a>
  <br>
  <a href="https://site.com/imagens/2.jpg"> Link 2 </a>
  <br>
  <a href="https://site.com/imagens/3.jpg"> Link 3 </a>
  <br>
  <a href="https://site.com/imagens/4.jpg"> Link 4 </a>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="ObterLinks()">Obter Links </button>

<div id="divResultado">

</div>
```